# Add a Widget To Website displaying Facebook Messages/Activity

Tags: facebook, android-activity, widget, message

Am trying to add a widget to our homepage (vegetableseeds dot net). We have a facebook page facebook.com/vegetableseeds.net

There plenty of "messages"! on our facebook homepage (see attached image)

I cannot seem to find a widget that allows me to display these messages on our homepage.

I've tried the following, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity/
But when I enter our page address (facebook.com/vegetableseeds.net) It states there is no activty?

There is tonnes of activity, so i must be doing something wrong?

Any advice appreciated

Many thanks
Ben

Answer (score 3):

I believe the option you are looking for is a Like Box

[Facebook Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/)

If you click all the option 'Show Posts' it will show all the recent posts by the page itself, then all you have to do is embed the 'like box' into your page.

Comment: Hi Crawdingle - thks for that - the problem is that this solution displays my posts - what I really want is customers posts to be displayed - On our Facebook page the customers comments appear in a box called "Messages". It does not seem possible to display these messages in a widget - the reason I'm keen on this is that many of the comments are positive and would act as testimonials - Tks Ben